# Install/copy Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (official) on Rasperry Pi 2 Type B

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, sd-card, raspberrypi

I'm using 16.04 on my computer, and want's to use 16.04 on my rasperry pi 2 as well. I'm trying to copy the data over to the Micro SD card, with the command `xzcat ubuntu.img.xz | sudo dd of=/dev/mmcblk0` as suggested on the website https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi, but it seems to take very long time (60 minutes +) and I suspect it to be something wrong. When I installed 14.04 (un-official) it didn't taker more than a few minutes to copy into the SD-card.

I have checked that my SD is identified as /dev/mmcblk0 and it is unmounted from the system. Have tried to delete every partitions on the card as well (with Gparted), to ensure nothing is mounted somewhere with a mistake.

RPi's own documentation suggest somehow a litle different command, but since the img on Ubuntu's website is compressed (img.xz) I think I need to `xzcat` the content first, and therefore cant use the command from RPi.

Have also tried to change the bs option, but that doesn't seem to speed up anything. I'm on my fourth try, now with `bs=32M` as suggested [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/), but doesn't seem to change much other than it started on 1,3 GB instead of a few MB when I didn't specify bs.

This is output from `sudo pkill -USR1 -n -x dd`

```
0+157946 records in
0+157946 records out
1348820992 bytes (1,3 GB, 1,3 GiB) copied, 58,5943 s, 23,0 MB/s
0+157948 records in
0+157948 records out
1349099520 bytes (1,3 GB, 1,3 GiB) copied, 72,1942 s, 18,7 MB/s
0+157951 records in
0+157951 records out
1349386240 bytes (1,3 GB, 1,3 GiB) copied, 86,1943 s, 15,7 MB/s
0+157984 records in
0+157984 records out
1353392128 bytes (1,4 GB, 1,3 GiB) copied, 263,002 s, 5,1 MB/s
0+158055 records in
0+158055 records out
1359421440 bytes (1,4 GB, 1,3 GiB) copied, 384,202 s, 3,5 MB/s
0+158210 records in
0+158210 records out
1373396992 bytes (1,4 GB, 1,3 GiB) copied, 628,222 s, 2,2 MB/s
0+160165 records in
0+160165 records out
1443610624 bytes (1,4 GB, 1,3 GiB) copied, 1085,44 s, 1,3 MB/s
0+163605 records in
0+163605 records out
1562771456 bytes (1,6 GB, 1,5 GiB) copied, 1593,89 s, 980 kB/s
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up letting it run for about 10 hours, and when I woke up everything seemed to be copied. Don't know why it took so long, as its a Class 10 card - but anyway; now it works!